# Allow XSD date element to be empty string

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I would like to allow an element to be a `xs:date` or an empty string.

Here's an XML Schema that I've tried:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:lp="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:lokalplan:1" 
           targetNamespace="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:lokalplan:1" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" xml:lang="DA" 
           xmlns:m="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:metadata:1">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="../key.xsd" namespace="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:metadata:1" />
  <xs:element name="DatoVedtaget" type="lp:DatoVedtagetType" />
  <xs:complexType name="DatoVedtagetType">
    <xs:simpleContent>      
      <xs:extension base="xs:date">
        <xs:attribute ref="m:key" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DatoVedtagetTypeString">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute ref="m:key" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I want the element to be `DatoVedtagetType` in a case it includes a value, and I want it to be `DatoVedtagetTypeString` if it is empty.   How I implement such a conditional functionality this schema?

Comment: Isn't that just a convoluted way of saying you'd like `DatoVedtaget` to be a `xs:date` or empty?

Comment: Yes if it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comments on the question, the goal is to have `DatoVedtaget` be a `xs:date` or empty.  Here is a way to express such a constraint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:lp="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:lokalplan:1"
           xmlns:m="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:metadata:1"
           targetNamespace="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:lokalplan:1"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xml:lang="DA">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="../key.xsd" namespace="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:metadata:1" />
  <xs:element name="DatoVedtaget" type="lp:DatoVedtagetType" />

  <xs:simpleType name="empty">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value=""/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="dateOrEmpty">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:date lp:empty"/>
  </xs:simpleType>  

  <xs:complexType name="DatoVedtagetType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="lp:dateOrEmpty">
        <xs:attribute ref="m:key" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a union type as @kjhughes does, my own preferred solution is to use a list type allowing zero or one occurrences:

```
<xs:simpleType name="dateOrEmpty">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:date" maxLength="1"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

One reason for the preference is that it's less code. Another reason is that if you're writing schema-aware XSLT or XQuery code, the resulting value is easier to manipulate (the atomized value has type xs:date? which is easier to manipulate, e.g. to test for empty, than a union type).

Comment: Well, had I thought about it for an extra year, I might have come up with this `xs:list` idea too.  :-)   Seriously: I like this approach.  Nice solution.