# How to Assign NULL to XS:date XML Format

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, salesforce

I am Integrating the SalesForce CRM in Visual Studio 2015, here i want to to assign Null for XS:date XML Format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the XSD, you might redefine type field from being strictly `xs:date` to being

```
<xs:simpleType name="dateOrEmpty">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:date" maxLength="1"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40396904/290085) by Michael Kay in a [question regarding how to allow an XSD date to be an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33343231/290085).