# Setting max length of integer as 0 in xsd

Tags: xsd, integer, xsd-validation

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Rinteger">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
<xsd:maxLength value="0"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

maxLength is not allowed in integer. I tried totaDigits but value=0 is not allowed for it. How can I set the max length of an integer as 0 in schema?

Comment: Hi kjhughes, this question is for an integer field and the other question was for the date field which is why they are different questions! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but the answer is the same:  You can't concurrently constrain a field to be an integer (or a date) and also force its length to zero.  And if you actually mean *alternatively* an integer or an empty string, the answer on the duplicate link also applies since it references [***Allow XSD date element to be empty string***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33343231/290085), which shows how to allow either a datatype or an empty string.