# Setting max length of date type as 0 in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Date10">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date">
    <xsd:pattern value="??"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The date field shouldn't be able to accept any value in it. I want it to appear like an empty tag. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements contradict each other.  You cannot constrain an element to be a date and also to be empty concurrently because dates cannot have zero length.

If you intend to allow *either* a date *or* an empty string, see ***[Allow XSD date element to be empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33343231/290085)***.